# Fast computation of eigenvectors of perturbed matrix

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

Given a real symmetric matrix $A$, say we already know its spectral decomposition $A = UDU^T$. We wish to compute the spectral decomposition of $A+E$, where $E$ is a small matrix (I am particularly interested in the case where E is nonzero in only one entry).

I know this places us squarely in the domain of perturbation theory, which is of course a richly studied topic. However, I am interested in an algorithm which can numerically solve this quickly, and which I could quickly implement or find prepackaged in Matlab or Python. I am sure such a thing exists but I am having trouble finding it. **Can anyone provide me with a reference to such an algorithm?**

For context, I need to compute the eigenvectors of $A$, then perturb it a tiny bit, and then recompute the eigenvectors, and then repeat many times. Recomputing the vectors from scratch each time is slow and seems wasteful.

Comment: This may answer your question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3052997/rank-one-update-of-eigenvalues

If $E$ has one non-zero entry it's rank-one. The author lists the Netlib routine. I don't think it'd be right to copy it. 

http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d2/d24/group__aux_o_t_h_e_rcomputational_ga3c4a943599132aea3ac964c08392853a.html

Comment: +1 for @RyanHowe: this is definitely the canonical way to solve this problem. Be aware of implementing this yourself: it is very tricky to solve this problem accurately. Demmel's book as referenced in the linked answer does a good job of explaining the difficulties. For particularly structured eigenvector computations, this method can further be accelerated by the fast multipole method. There's some discussion in [this paper](rb.gy/bff9jj) if you're interested. Unfortunately, I don't believe there's a publically available high-quality implementation of this accelerated variant.

Comment: @eepperly16 thanks