# Matrix exponential of a rank-$1$ correction of a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, matrix-exponential

Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix and $A$ be a rank-$1$ matrix. I want to compute the matrix exponential $ e^{D+A}$, if possible by diagonalization of the matrix $D+A$. Is there a way of computing the diagonalization of this rank-$1$-correction of a diagonal matrix efficiently and in a numerically stable way, like the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula for the inverse?

Comment: One approach is to use the algorithm explained [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3052997/81360) to get the eigenvalue decomposition of $D + A$, then apply the usual exponentiation algorithm for a diagonalizable matrix.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to require that the correction $A$ is symmetric, which is not the case for me.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. Still, a similar approach might be applicable here.

Comment: Is $\bf D$ positive definite?