# Orthogonal diagonalization of dummy variables vectors covariance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and let $(p_i)_{i \in \{1,\cdots,n\}}$ be a finite sequence of real numbers, that are assumed to be nonnegative and sum to $1$. Let us denote by $\mathbf{p}$ the column vector of the $p_i$'s.

We consider the $n\times n$ matrix $CV_p := Diag(p_1,\cdots ,p_n) - \mathbf{p}\mathbf{p}^T$.

Let also $Y$ be a random variable such that for all $i \in \{1, \cdots, n\}$, $\mathbb{P}[Y = i] = p_i$. Let us denote by $X$ the dummy-variable encoding of $Y$, that is, $X_i := \delta_{Y,i}$.

Then $CV_p$ is the covariance matrix of $X$: indeed, if $i,j \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$, $\mathbb{E}[(\delta_{Y,i} - \mathbb{E}[\delta_{Y,i}] )(\delta_{Y,j} - \mathbb{E}[\delta_{Y,j}])]$ equals $p_i(1-p_i)$ if $i=j$ and $-p_ip_j$ if $i \neq j$.

Indeed, $\mathbb{E}[\delta_{Y,i}] = p_i$, and

$\mathbb{E}[(\delta_{Y,i} - \mathbb{E}[\delta_{Y,i}] )(\delta_{Y,j} - \mathbb{E}[\delta_{Y,j}])]\\
 = \mathbb{E}[(\delta_{Y,i} - p_i )(\delta_{Y,j} - p_j)]\\
 = \mathbb{E}[\delta_{Y,i}\delta_{Y,j}] - p_ip_j - p_jp_i + p_ip_j\\
 = \mathbb{E}[\delta_{Y,i}\delta_{Y,j}] - p_ip_j.$

Now, if $i=j$, $\mathbb{E}[\delta_{Y,i}\delta_{Y,j}] = \mathbb{E}[\delta_{Y,i}] = p_i$, so we get $\mathbb{E}[(\delta_{Y,i} - \mathbb{E}[\delta_{Y,i}] )(\delta_{Y,j} - \mathbb{E}[\delta_{Y,j}])] = \mathbb{E}[\delta_{Y,i}\delta_{Y,j}] - p_ip_j = p_i(1-p_i)$.

And if $i\neq j$, $\delta_{Y,i}\delta_{Y,j} = 0$, so $\mathbb{E}[(\delta_{Y,i} - \mathbb{E}[\delta_{Y,i}] )(\delta_{Y,j} - \mathbb{E}[\delta_{Y,j}])] = \mathbb{E}[\delta_{Y,i}\delta_{Y,j}] - p_ip_j = -p_ip_j$.

Is it possible to provide explicit (in terms of the $p_i$'s) and beautiful formulae for the spectrum of $CV_p$? Of an orthogonal diagonalization matrix?

Comment: This is an instance of a generally intractable problem (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3052997/81360) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/104177/34894)), so I suspect that the answer is no.

Comment: See [these notes](http://www.cs.yale.edu/publications/techreports/tr916.pdf) for how the BNS formula can be used here

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that $\Bbb E[\delta_{Y,i}\delta_{Y,j}] = 0$? Shouldn't it be the case that $\Bbb P[Y = i \text{ and } Y = j] = 0$ when $i \neq j$?

Comment: Regardless of its derivation, the matrix $CV_p$ is indeed a covariance matrix of some kind, and it has rank $n-1$ as long as all $p_i$ are positive. The row-sums of $CV_p$ are all equal to $0$, to $CV_p$ will have $(1,1,\dots,1)$ as an eigenvector associated with $0$.

Comment: I recommend that you consider the similar matrix
$$
M = W^*(CV_p)W,
$$
where $W$ denotes a [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix) and $W^*$ denotes a conjugate-transpose. Note that the first row and column of $M$ are $0$, corresponding to the zero-eigenvalue of $CV_p$.

Comment: Thank you for the references! If you gather everything into an answer, I'll accept it! What's wrong with the formulas? I added details to my derivation.

Comment: Your work is correct; I had made a mistake when computing the covariance matrix for your random variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an instance of a generally intractable problem (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3052997/81360) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/104177/34894)). Numerically, we can make some use of the structure of the matrix in order to quickly find eigenvalues using the BNS algorithm, as is [explained here](http://www.cs.yale.edu/publications/techreports/tr916.pdf).

A few things that can be said about $CV_p$: $CV_p$ has rank $n-1$ as long as all $p_i$ are non-zero (more generally, the rank is equal to the size of the support of the distribution of $Y$). Its kernel is spanned by the vector $(1,1,\dots,1)$.

One strategy that might yield some insight is looking at the similar matrix $M = W^*C_pW$, where $W$ denotes the [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix). The fact that the first column of $W$ spans the kernel means that the first row and column of $M$ will be zero. Empirically, there seems to be some kind of structure in the entries of the resulting matrix (for instance, repeated entries along the diagonal).