# Sum of Identity and Gram Matrix written as Gram Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let $G = AA^T$ be a gram matrix with
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 
| & & | \\ 
d_1 & \dots & d_k \\
| & & |
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $d_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $n>k$. We are now interested in the sum of the identity $\mathbb{I}$ with the gram matrix $G$
$$
\mathbb{I} + G = \mathbb{I} + \sum_{i=1}^k d_i d_i^T.
$$

I am looking for $B$ such that
$$
\mathbb{I} + G = BB^T
$$

#### Special Case

If the $d_i$ are orthogonal, we can complete them into an orthonormal basis $Q = (\frac{d_1}{\|d_1\|},\dots,\frac{d_n}{\|d_n\|})$ and immediately obtain the eigendecomposition
$$
Q^T(\mathbb{I} + G) Q =  \mathbb{I} + \text{diag}(\|d_1\|^2,\dots, \|d_k\|^2, 0\dots,0)
$$
and thus
$$
   \mathbb{I} + G = B B^T
$$
with $B = \Bigl(\frac{\sqrt{1+\|d_1\|^2}}{\|d_1\|} d_1, \dots, \frac{\sqrt{1+\|d_k\|^2}}{\|d_k\|} d_k, \frac{d_{k+1}}{\|d_{k+1}\|}, \dots, \frac{d_n}{\|d_n\|}\Bigr)$.

In particular for $k=1$ this is always possible.

Now I am asking, whether or not something similar is possible if the $d_i$ are not orthogonal and have to be orthogonalized first. I could not make it work so far.

Comment: One approach to getting $B$ numerically is to apply $k$ successive [rank-1 updates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Rank-one_update), starting with $I = II^T$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann "rank-1 update" is the term I needed to get useful search results. Thank you! Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3052997/eigenvalues-of-a-rank-one-update-of-a-matrix