# What is the eigendecomposition of a matrix that incudes another matrix for which we know the eigendecomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Let $A$ be a real square matrix of size $n$ by $n$ that have the following eigendecomposition $A = PDP^{-1}$.
What can be said about the eigendecomposition of another real square matrix $B$ of size $n+1$ by $n+1$ that "includes" $A$, with the form:
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
c & v^T \\
v & A
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $c$ is a real constant and $v$ is a real vector of size $v$?

What if $A$ is symmetric? What if $c = 1$ or $c = 0$?

I wonder is there exists a nested relation between eigenelements of $B$ and those of $A$.

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric, your matrix is symmetric hence diagonalizable

Comment: [Does this help?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3052997/eigenvalues-of-a-rank-one-update-of-a-matrix)

Comment: @RobertIsrael I am not sure to see the link with rank-1 update

Comment: @T.L  $B$ is a rank-$1$ update of $\pmatrix{0 & 0\cr v & A\cr}$, whose eigenvalues are $0$ and those of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the case of the $1 \times 1$ matrix $A = [1]$. Its only eigenvalue is $1$. In this case, both $v$ and $c$ are numbers, so we're looking at eigenvalues of
$$
\pmatrix{
c & v \\
v & 1
}
$$
i.e., roots of
$$
(c-x)(1-x) - v^2 = 0,
$$
which is just
$$
x^2 - (c+1)x - v^2 = 0,
$$
whose roots are
$$
\frac{(c+1) \pm \sqrt{(c+1)^2 + 4v^2}}{2}
$$
Letting $u = (c+1)/2$, this becomes
$$
x_1, x_2 = u \pm \sqrt{u^2 + v^2}
$$

Pick any two numbers $a$ and $b$. If you set $u = \frac{a+b}{2}$, then for any $v$ you get
$$
x_1 + x_2 = a + b \\
x_1 - x_2 = \sqrt{\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2 + v^2} 
$$
Setting this second thing to be $a-b$ gives you
\begin{align}
(a - b) &= \sqrt{\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2 + v^2} \\
(a - b)^2 &= \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2 + v^2 \\
(a - b)^2 - \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2 &=  v^2 \\
a^2 -2ab + b^2 + \frac{a^2}{2} + ab + \frac{b^2}{2} &= v^2\\
\frac{3a^2}{2} -ab + \frac{3b^2}{2} &= v^2\\
\end{align}
so we can let
$$
v = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2} (a^2 + b^2) - ab}
$$
and we'll have arranged for the two eigenvalues of our matrix to be $a$ and $b$.

In short: Knowing that the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $1$ tells you nothing about the potential eigenvalues of $$
\pmatrix{
c & v \\
v & 1
}
$$

Comment: That doesn't say it tells you "nothing".  It just says the answer depends on more than just the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Fair enough, Robert. But I'd say that it at least answers OP's original, "I wonder is there exists a nested relation between eigenelements of $$ and those of $$". It was that more narrow thing that I was addressing. Clearly if $v = 0$, then the eigenvalues are those of $A$, together with $c$.